Mellin transform of confluent Lauricella hypergeometric function
The $F_D^{(n)} $ Lauricella's hypergeometric function can be defined as follow
$$F_D\left(a,b_1,\cdots,b_n;c;x_1,\cdots,x_n\right) = \sum_{m_1=0,\cdots,m_n=0}^{\infty}\frac{\left(a\right)_{m_1+\cdots+m_n}\left(b_1\right)_{m_1}\cdots\left(b_n\right)_{m_n}}{\left(c\right)_{m_1+\cdots+m_n}m_1!\cdots m_n!}x^{m_1}\cdots x^{m_n}$$
where $(a)_m = \frac{\Gamma\left(a+m\right)}{\Gamma\left(a\right)}$. The confluent Lauricella's hypergeometric function $\Phi^{(n)}_2$ can be obtained from the $F_D^{(n)}$ as follow
$$\Phi^{(n)}_2\left(b_1,\cdots,b_n;c;x_1,\cdots,x_n\right) = \sum_{m_1=0,\cdots,m_n=0}^{\infty}\frac{\left(b_1\right)_{m_1}\cdots\left(b_n\right)_{m_n}}{\left(c\right)_{m_1+\cdots+m_n}m_1!\cdots m_n!}x^{m_1}\cdots x^{m_n}\\
= \lim_{|a|\to\infty} F_D\left(a,b_1,\cdots,b_n;c;\frac{x_1}{a},\cdots,\frac{x_n}{a}\right)$$
I know that $F_D\left(a,b_1,\cdots,b_n;c;x_1,\cdots,x_n\right)$ can be represented using Mellin-Barnes type contour integrals as follow (refer to Exton equation 2.5.8 page 53)
$$F_D\left(a,b_1,\cdots,b_n;c;x_1,\cdots,x_n\right) = \frac{\Gamma(c)}{\Gamma(a)\Gamma(b_1)\cdots\Gamma(b_n)}\frac{1}{(2\pi i)^n}\times\\
\int\cdots\int \frac{\Gamma(a+t_1+\cdots+t_n)\Gamma(b_1+t_1)\cdots \Gamma(b_n+t_n)}{\Gamma(c+t_1+\cdots+t_n)}\Gamma(-t_1)\cdots\Gamma(-t_n)(-x_1)^{t_1}\cdots(-x_n)^{t_n}dt_1\cdots dt_n$$
I'm guessing such complex representations can be constructed form the humble representation $e^{-x}=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{-i\infty}^{i\infty}\Gamma(-s)x^s ds$ by multiplying them $n$-fold and then taking the Mellin transform of the result. However I could not find any Mellin-Barnes type representation for the confluent Lauricella hypergeometric function $\Phi_2^{(n)}$ anywhere!
Am I wrong? Does it exist at all? Can it be expressed in closed form or using special functions?
Any hints is appreciated, Thank you!
